# Send data between jars?

Tags: java, jar

I'm creating an application that has two jars: the launcher and the client. How may I send data from the launcher to the client, besides sending variables one by one through command line parameters ?

Edit: Both jars exist on the same machine and for now, the launcher launches the client by a line of code similar to the following.

```
String[] commands = {"java", "-Djava.library.path=natives", "-jar", "Client.jar",
                          "Client argument 1", ... , "Client argument N"};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Comment: Sockets, HTTP, JMS, ...

Comment: Give us some more information: do the two applications run on the same machine?  How does the launcher start the client?

Comment: You can use Java Remote Method Invocation [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html)

Comment: Couldn't you just put both jars on the same classpath and call the methods from each others' classes?  It seems like both of the jars are on the same local machine.

Comment: I don't have any experience with java since I just started using java, so I'll have to look on how to do that.

Comment: What is the purpose of the launcher?

Comment: @AdelBoutros I'm using two jars because the launcher is checking for updates and when necessary downloads them and replaces the old client.

Comment: You can also use simple files. Write to the file in the launcher and read from it in the client.

Comment: java.util.Properties can be used to load from a simple ini style file. You can have some code that finds the file (can search in one or two locations) and then once it gets the input stream call the load(InputStream) method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the following solutions to my problem:

**Using the same class-path**
Multiple jars can be put under the same class-path in order to be able to call each other methods. This can be achieved by adding the following line to the manifest file of the first jar launched, from what I understood.

```
Class-Path: lwjgl.jar libs/AnotherJarFile.jar
```

Source: [LWJGL Wiki](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application)

**Using secondary files**
Simple text files can be used to transmit data between multiple jars. The easiest way that this can be achieved, in my opinion is through XML serialization.

Comment: i guess what this is saying is use the same jvm. once the launcher has got the latest jars or decided everything is already in place, then it can simply call the real apps main method directly by instantiating it, and pass params as method parameters

Comment: you should use a tool to make the manifest or be careful - if the length is more than 72 to go to next line as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest

Answer (score 0):

If the launcher is updating the client then surely you can create a structure where your client can read from and the launcher can update.

The most obvious structure would be a folder where all the updatable files would be stored.

The launcher replaces the content of the files on update and the client reads them.

**What's even better:**

Integrate the launcher's code into the client code and make the client responsible for updating and reading those files.